# Why was this question on good and evil in literature put on hold

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, specific-question

I am staggered to see that [How can I have a war with no "good" or "evil" side?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/29446/how-can-i-have-a-war-with-no-good-or-evil-side) has been put on hold as a what to write question. It is a question about the role of good and evil in the construction of a story. If that is not of general interest, I don't know what is.

Yes, it was asked in terms of a specific project, but using examples from your own work to illustrate a question is supposed to be fine. Could it have been more explicit about this? Sure. And anyone who felt it was not sufficiently specific on this could have edited it accordingly.

But the core of this question is clearly of broad interest. Far narrower questions are asked and answered here every day without a single close vote.

Comment: I think the question could probably be edited and reopened. Do you have any suggestions about how to go about this? As to other questions remaining open - we could probably stand to have the line between what-should-I-write and how-do-I-solve-this-problem clarified.

Comment: @NeilFein I think the rewrite is fairly simple: just a matter of phrasing the question more generally and couching the specific case as an example. I would have done the edit, but now it is closed it won't let me.

Comment: Thanks, have reopened the question - go ahead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has been edited and reopened. Thanks for bringing this up!

Answer (score 0):

I really believe there is a correlation between the "what to write" restriction, the multiplicity of similar questions coming up on the site (for lack of possible alternatives) and the fact that potential rival SEs for writing are being organized. If the rules remain so restrictive here, I do not think this SE will succeed, nor will it deserve to. Just my two cents.

Comment: It's catch 22. If we allowed what to write questions generally we would be buried in homework and revisions questions that would be of no use to anyone but the author -- which would make this a forum, not a Q&A site. But in technical fields there are often objectively correct, or at least conventional ways to say things that recur frequently, so the question can be generalized and the answer can be of use to more than one person. For example: https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/26982/documenting-the-no-args-call-of-a-command-line-program